# Blazemeter Oauth plugin for JMeter no longer supports authentication using OAuth 1.0?

Tags: oauth, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, oauth-1.0a, blazemeter

I need to test HTTPS requests with OAuth 1.0 as the authentication method. I tried using the deprecated plugins with older versions, and the Blazemeter script for the same, but neither of them work. I just need to pass the Consumer Key and Secret and sign the HTTPS request with OAuth 1.0 using Jmeter. Can anyone help here please?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter has never supported OAuth per se, so I would recommend using [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) in order to sign your request.

Check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article which has an example of bypassing OAuth 1.0 challenge using [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) scripting and [oauth-signpost](https://github.com/mttkay/signpost) library.

The approach is not guaranteed to work for all OAuth implementations as there could be many encryption options so you may need to modify the code according to your infrastructure.